# Webshopapps Premium Matrix Rates - php7.1 compatibility

Tags: magento-1.9

Webshopapps has deprecated their much used matrix rate modules, so they won't support PHP7.1+, which means a lot of people cannot upgrade php to a secure version.

The issues are fx. the use of pushing strings to arrays shorthand ([]).

```
&$itemGroup = array()
$itemGroup[] = $item;
```

How do i fix these type of compability issues?

Answer (score 4):

I've found a way to fix this on one our client's Magento 1.9 websites.

In the **app/code/community/Webshopapps/Wsacommon/Helper/Shipping.php** file, there is a function called **getItemInclFreeTotals**. We've found that it was breaking on the following line (around line 312 I believe):

```
self::processItemGroup($itemGroup, $item);
```

We added a check in to determine if the variable **$itemGroup** was an array or not. If you add the following lines of codes above the line earlier in the post:

```
// Applying fix for PHP 7.2
if (!is_array($itemGroup) && empty($itemGroup)) {
    $itemGroup = array();
}
```

We've been able to load in the relevant shipping rates on our website.

The final code for the whole function:

```
$freeMethodWeight = $totals->getFreeMethodWeight();

// Applying fix for PHP 7.2
if (!is_array($itemGroup) && empty($itemGroup)) {
    $itemGroup = array();
}

self::processItemGroup($itemGroup, $item);

return true;
```